# Can I send/receive data from two Bluetooth devices at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

On my Windows laptop, I have two paired devices - my mouse and my speakers. When my mouse is idle, the music will play on speakers with no problems, but as soon as I start moving my mouse, the music on the speakers stops and starts lagging.

Is it possible for Windows (or wherever the problem rests) to simultaneously send/receive Bluetooth data from two different devices?

I haven't been able to find anything on Google regarding this problem, except that it is possible for multiple devices to work together. Mouse is Razer Orochi, speakers are LG NB3520A, and Bluetooth device is Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) 4.0 + High Speed Adapter. Laptop is HP Envy 3270nr.

Comment: **What research have you done? Have you tried anything to resolve this?** Adding these details will improve your question. Also, IMO, this is more of a hardware issue than Windows, so **[edit]** your question with details about the computer and Bluetooth devices so we can help you.

Comment: i've added the information you mentioned